# Notation question: $R(A)=\mathbb{C}^2$ with $A\in End(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, notation, linear-transformations

I have a map, represented by the matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\1 & 1\end{array}\right)=End(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
My teacher wrote in his lecture notes that because it is invertible, we can conclude that $R(A)=\mathbb{C}^2$. To me it looks like he means that the range of the map is $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the complex part of all imaginary numbers equal to zero, which seems a bit odd when he defined $A\in End(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Am I correct, or does $\mathbb{C}$ not denote the complex numbers in this case?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix. Whichever field $k$ you choose, it will represent an endomorphism of $k^2$; moreover, that endomorphism will be injective and surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have your notes, but yes, the most likely interpretation is that this is a typo for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: (assuming that the notes really do say $A \in \text{End} (\mathbb{R}^2)$.)

Comment: Which they do. He defined $A\in End(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Comment: Again, I don't have your notes.

Comment: Well no, but I guess the most natural thing for me is to explain the notes, right?